# How do I automatically log the contents of a JupyterLab output cell?

Tags: logging, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

(Note: I'm already logging info as my python code runs.)  I've got my code set up to print various useful notes to the JupyterLab output cell(s) as it runs.  I want to automatically save off all of these notes, so that I don't lose them when I need to restart the kernel.

I could send these notes to the log file I've already got using `logging.info('useful note here')`, but then they'd get lost among all the thousands of other info notifications.  I'm looking for a way specifically save only the output cell(s) contents to file, without having to manually cut & paste them into a text file.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [scrapbook](https://github.com/nteract/scrapbook)?

Comment: Hrm, I think I might be!  Either that or the [papermill](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/) that scrapbook's descrip refers to...?  I'll install and experiment; thx.